# Tools for documenting and mapping APIs with application's user interface for impact analysis

Tags: rest, api, user-interface, microservices, impact-analysis

I work on developing API services that internally call multiple micro-services

I was looking for a tool that could help me map public facing APIs with the application's user interface (application is available as native android/ios and PWA)

We do use tools like Swagger and NewRelic for internally maintaining API related details and documentation. However, I was trying to look up any tool(preferably open-source) that could help me map the api calls with the user interface

For example:
A Homepage Screen for the app with multiple buttons. Each button makes a REST API call. These REST APIs internally call micro services.
I would like to have a UI based tool where I could show the Homepage screen for the app(a screenshot) and then write APIs endpoints and routes associated to each button.

The reason I am looking to do this is because I believe this will make new people on the team(and external stakeholders) easier to read and refer to the application flow and how it is tied to the REST APIs. This will also make impact analysis easier when making changes to certain services/APIs

Comment: Are you looking for a sitemap?

Comment: No, a sitemap is not what I am looking for

Comment: One idea... If you have a test automation framework in place (let's say Selenium WebDriver), you could take screen shots during your tests and document REST API somewhere. It's possible to automate a document creation this way with screens and API.

Comment: I could do that without an automation framework but the problem is maintaining that is going to need a lot of manual intervention and an additional skill set to keep updating such framework. What I am looking for is a tool already built to do this or anything that’s at least close